# Slope whats the error in this problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Kyle graphed a line, given a slope of 43
 and the
point (2, 3). When he used the slope to find the second point, he
found (5, 7). What error did Kyle make

Comment: You should at least show some effort, I think.

Comment: A slope of $43$?  You sure that's right?

Comment: I think you should put some effort into such elementary questions; you clearly are _not_ Kyle.

Answer (score 7):

Kyle mistook slope of $43$ to be slope of $4/3 = \dfrac{4}{3} = \dfrac{\text{rise}}{\text{run}} = \dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.

Then given the point $(2, 3)$, ***if slope were*** $4/3$, a second point on the line would indeed be $(2 + 3, 3 + 4) = (5, 7).\;$ And the equation for the line would be $$y - 3 = \dfrac 43 (x - 2) \quad \iff \quad y = \frac43x + \frac13$$

So...if slope was clearly given to be $43$, then either Kyle needs glasses, or else he didn't know what the he was doing! $43 \ne \dfrac{4}{3}$!

Comment: It could be $43^o$ as well, I think :)

Comment: Not quite, @Kaster. The angle would need to be $\approx 53.13^\circ$ to get the point $(5, 7)$! But creative thought!

Comment: +1. I wonder how Kyle reached intermediate algebra before working on his arithmetic.

Comment: @DumbCow Good question!